# Is Monad just a functional way of Error handling?

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type

I am reading **"Programming in Haskell"** book and trying to correlate ideas of haskell to my knowledge in C#. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I feel like monads enforces the programmer to write code which can handle exceptions. So we will explicitly mention the error handling in the type system like

```
Optional(Int) functionName(Int a, Int b)
```

The return type is Optional(Int) but not an Int, So who so ever uses the library that has this kind of return types will understand that error handling is happening and the result will be like None(explains Something went wrong) and Some(explains we got some result).

Any code can result to Happy Path(where we get some results) and Sad Path(where errors occurs). Making this paths explicitly in Type system is what monad is. That's my understanding of it. Please correct me.

Monads are like a bridge between Pure Functional Programming and Impure code (that results in side effects).

---

Apart from this I want to make sure my understanding on Exception handling (VS) Option Types.

Exception Handling tries to do the operations without having a deeper look on to the inputs. Exception Handling's are Heavy since the Call stack has to unwind till it get to the Catch || Rescue || Handling Code.

And the Functional way of dealing things is check the inputs before doing the operations and return the **"None"** as result if the inputs does't match the required criteria. Option types are light weight of handling errors.

Comment: `Optional` is just a single instance of `Monad`. There are many others.

Comment: Note that in C one doesn’t have `option` or monads or exceptions however there is still error handling

Answer (score 5):

`Monad` is just an interface (in Haskell terms, typeclass) that a type can implement, along with a contract specifying some restrictions on how the interface should behave.

It's not that different from how a C# type `T` can implement, say, the `IComparable<T>` interface. However, the `Monad` interface is quite abstract and the functions can do surprisingly different things for different types (but always respecting the same laws, and the same "flavor" of composition).

Instead of seeing `Monad` as a functional way of error handling, it's better to go the other way: inventing a type like `Optional` that represents errors / absence of values, and start devising useful functions on that type. For example, a function that produces an "inhabited" `Optional` from an existing value, a function that composes two `Optional`-returning functions to minimize repetitive code, a function that changes the value inside the `Optional` if it exists, and so on. All of them functions that can be useful on their own.

*After* we have the type and and a bevy of useful functions, we might ask ourselves:

- Does the type itself fit the requirements for `Monad`? It must have a type parameter, for example.
- Do *some* (not necessarily all) of the useful functions we have discovered for the type fit the `Monad` interface? Not only they must fit the signatures, they must fit the contract.

In the affirmative case, good news! We can define a `Monad` instance for the type, and now we are able to use a whole lot of [monad-generic functions](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#g:4) for free!

But even if the `Monad` typeclass doesn't exist in our language, we can keep in mind that the type and some of the functions defined on it behave like a `Monad`. From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenCompose-java.util.function.Function-) of the `thenCompose` method of the `CompletableFuture` Java class:

> This method is analogous to Optional.flatMap and Stream.flatMap.

This allows us to "transfer intuitions" between seemingly unrelated classes, even if we can't write monad-generic code because the shared interface doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Monads aren't 'just a functional way of error handling', so you are, indeed, wrong.

It would be pointless to turn this answer into a monad tutorial, so I'm not  going to try. It takes some time to understand what a monad is, and the best advice I can give is to keep working with the concept until it clicks. Eventually it will.

The type described in the OP looks equivalent (*isomorphic*) to Haskell's more standard `Maybe` type, which is indeed a monad. In a pinch, it can be used for error handling, but more often you'd use another monad called `Either` (or types isomorphic to it), since it's better suited for that task.

A monad, though, can be many other things. Lists are monads, as are functions themselves (via the *Reader* monad). Trees are monads as well. These have nothing to do with error handling.

When it comes to exceptions in Haskell, I take the view that it's a legacy feature. I'd never design my Haskell code around exceptions, since exceptions aren't visible via the type system. When a function may fail to return a result, I'd let it return a `Maybe`, an `Either`, or another type isomorphic to that. This will, indeed, force the caller to handle not only the happy path, but also any failures that may occur.

Comment: Sir, I'm trying to understand how Lists are monads. That means a List can be empty(which is not of type int) or it may have at-least one integer. Can you please share any helpful resource that can compare the haskell Ideas to some object oriented programming.

Comment: @PKChem Funny you should ask: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/10/04/from-design-patterns-to-category-theory This, however, doesn't cover monads yet, but I'd be surprised if ultimately it doesn't get there.

Comment: For most purposes, a function that returns an `Either` value looks an awful lot like a function that can raise type-checked exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

> Is Monad just a functional way of Error handling?

No it is not. The most prominent use for monads is handling side-effecting computations in Haskell. They can also be used for error handling, but the reason they are called "monads" and not "error handlers" is that they provide a common abstraction around several seemingly different things. For instance, in Haskell, `join` is a synonym for `concat` and `=<<` is an infix synonym for `concatMap`.

> Monads are like a bridge between Pure Functional Programming and Impure code (that results in side effects).

This is a subtle point. In a lazy language such as Haskell, *side effects* refer to computations which may indeed be pure, such as FFI calls that require memory to be freed upon completion. Monads provide a way to track (and perform) side effects. "Pure" simply means "function returns the same value when called with the same value".